# How to solve the equation $\log_2(x-9)+\log_{(2x-18)}6=3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, quadratics

> Solve the following equation. $$\log_2(x-9)+\log_{(2x-18)}6=3.$$

I tried this way,

\begin{align}
  \log_2(x-9)+\log_{(2x-18)}6 & \ = \ 3\\
  \log_2(x-9)+\log_{2(x-9)}6 & \ = \ 3\\
  \log_2(x-9)+\frac{\log_{2}6}{\log_2(2(x-9))} & \ = \ 3\\
  \log_2(x-9)+\frac{\log_{2}6}{1+\log_2(x-9)} & \ = \ 3\\
  u+\frac{\log_{2}6}{1+u} & \ = \ 3&&\text{(when $ u=\log(x-9) $)}\\
  u(1+u)+\log_{2}6 & \ = \ 3(1+u)\\
  u^2-2u+(\log_{2}6-3) & \ = \ 0\\
  u & \ = \ \frac{2\pm\sqrt{-4\log_26+16}}{2}\\
  & \ = \ 1\pm\sqrt{-2\log_26+8}
\end{align}

Comment: You are almost done! Just consider $\log_2(x-9)=u=1\pm\sqrt{8-2\log_26}$ and solve it for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Now, $x=9+2^{1+\sqrt{4-\log_26}}$ or $x=9+2^{1-\sqrt{4-\log_26}}$

Comment: @Mundron Schmidt and Michael Rozenberg, Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: @somkiat_t You are welcome! It was a mistake in your computations. I fixed your mistake in my solution.